# PHP CURL file upload being saved to Sharepoint instead of OneDrive

Tags: php, curl, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

I've come across a really weird (and a little alarming) problem.

1. I'm using Microsoft's sample users to test my integration - in this
   case Diego Siciliani
2. I'm using a File Type input to pass FormData to PHP via Ajax
3. The file upload gets saved to the organisation's shared folders in **Sharepoint**, instead of a specific personal folder in the user's **OneDrive**.

Here's my CURL:

```
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];

    $headers = array(
        "Authorization: Bearer " . $token, 
        "Host: graph.microsoft.com",
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Content-Length: 0",
    );

    $postfile = curl_init('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/' . $userid . '/drive/root:/{folder}/' . $filename . ':/content'); 
    curl_setopt($postfile, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
    curl_setopt($postfile, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
    curl_setopt($postfile, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
    $result = curl_exec($postfile); 
    curl_close($postfile);
```

This is what OneDrive looks like immediately after:
[image]

And this is what Sharepoint looks like immediately after:
[image]

Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a slight correction you will have to do.

The endpoint you are using

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/<userid>/drive/....
```

Will return only the root sharepoint Drive.

If you would like to use get the OneDrive URL other's person or your OneDrive you will have to use the below.

To access a specific user's one drive

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userid>/drive/...
```

To access yours, you could the below

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/...
```

To access  a specific users drive => `...v1.0/users/<userid>/...` instead of `...v1.0/<userid>/....`

**Note :**
You will need additional permission if you are accessing other person's onedrive.

Comment: your answer stopped the file being created in Sharepoint, but the file it now creates in the correct drive in OneDrive is empty (0 bytes). I've tried getting this right with many samples files of different times for hours now, and can't get it right.

Do you see anything in my cURL above that could be causing this, or if I've missed something?